# Subquery aggregation

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, roll-up-summary

When I attempt to use the following code I get an error with the subquery aggregation.  Is this not allowed in SOQL, or is there some other issue.  If it is not allowed, what would be the best alternative to the following:

```
for(Deal__c deal : [
    SELECT Rollup_Annual_Interest_Pymt_HE_Sr_Debt__c, 
        (
            SELECT SUM(Annual_Interest_Payment__c) InterestSum 
            FROM Loans__r 
            WHERE recordtype.developername = 'Loans_Held_Elsewhere' 
                AND payment_priority__c = 'Senior' 
        ) 
    FROM Deal__c
    WHERE isDeleted = false AND id =: loanIdList]) {
        deal.Rollup_Annual_Interest_Pymt_HE_Sr_Debt__c = deal.InterestSum;
        dealUpdateList.add(deal);   
}
```

Comment: Whenever you get an error message, you should include the text ***verbatim***.

Answer (score 8):

The error message makes it pretty clear:

> only root queries support aggregate expressions

So no, you can't use aggregate queries in a join.

I used a different query to get the error message, since you did not include the text:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(Id) FROM Opportunities) FROM Account
```

---

However, if you are looking to do a rollup via apex, I recommend you install and use [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), which allows you to craft rollup summaries in a declarative way. You won't have to write a single line of code yourself, and you'll get a back-fill batch for free (so you can update existing values org-wide).

Answer (score 5):

Aggregates are not allowed in sub-queries. Instead, you can aggregate the child records. Note that parents with no children will not include a row in the results.

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
    [SELECT Deal__r.Rollup_Annual_Interest_Pymt_HE_Sr_Debt__c Id,
            SUM(Annual_Interest_Payment__c) InterestSum 
     FROM Loan__c
     WHERE recordtype.developername = 'Loans_Held_Elsewhere' 
           AND payment_priority__c = 'Senior'
           AND Deal__c =: loanIdList]);

for(Deal__c record: Trigger.new) {
    if(results.containsKey(record.Id)) {
        record.Rollup_Annual_Interest_Pymt_HE_Sr_Debt__c = (Decimal)results.get(record.Id).get('InterestSum');
    } else {
        record.Rollup_Annual_Interest_Pymt_HR_Sr_Debt__c = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer presented by @Adrian, the workarounds to your (or any such problem) are

> **[Use Roll-up summaries](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=0)**

One thing to note is that both objects have to be in a **parent-child** relationship for this to work.

> Use Apex to aggregate **child** records

A similar example, [counting number of contacts on account](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/09/trigger-to-count-number-of-contacts.html) might help you to get going. You have not made your requirements clear in the question, so I guess that should provide you with enough information to get started.